# can we run code in mysql without creating a procedure

Tags: mysql, transactions

I want to create a sql file for my dba that will check whether index exists on a table. IF doesn't exist-create it.
I found many examples that use stored procedure, but I only want to run it once.

Something like this:

```
-- Creates an index if it does not already exist in MySQL.
START TRANSACTION;
SET IndexIsThere = 0;
SET given_table = 'IDR_CHGS';
SET given_index = 'FK_IDR_PATIENT_PT_ID_idx1';


SELECT COUNT(1) INTO IndexIsThere
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE  table_name  = given_table
    AND index_name  = given_index;

    IF IndexIsThere = 0 THEN
        SET @sqlstmt = CONCAT('CREATE INDEX ',given_index,' ON ', given_database,'.',given_table,' (',given_columns,')');
        PREPARE st FROM @sqlstmt;
        EXECUTE st;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
        SELECT CONCAT('Created index ', given_table,'.', given_index, ' on columns ', given_columns) AS 'CreateIndex status';
    ELSE
        SELECT CONCAT('Index ', given_index,' Already Exists on Table ', given_database,'.',given_table) AS 'CreateIndex status';
    END IF;

COMMIT;
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support IF/THEN/ELSE constructs outside of stored routines or triggers.

If you use PREPARE and EXECUTE, you could simply form a string that has the CREATE INDEX statement if there is no index, and a no-op statement (e.g. a comment) if not.

```
SELECT COALESCE(CONCAT('SELECT \'index ', S.INDEX_NAME, ' exists already\''), 
    'CREATE INDEX `idx_x` ON test.foo (`x`)') INTO @sql
FROM (SELECT NULL) AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS AS S
 ON (S.TABLE_SCHEMA, S.TABLE_NAME, S.INDEX_NAME) = ('test', 'foo', 'idx_x');

PREPARE s from @sql;
EXECUTE s;
```

If the index exists, `@sql` will be:

```
mysql> select @sql;
+-------------------------------------+
| @sql                                |
+-------------------------------------+
| SELECT 'index idx_x exists already' |
+-------------------------------------+
```

If the index does not exist, `@sql` will be:

```
mysql> select @sql;
+----------------------------------------+
| @sql                                   |
+----------------------------------------+
| CREATE INDEX `idx_x` ON test.foo (`x`) |
+----------------------------------------+
```

By the way, all CREATE and ALTER statements implicitly commit before and after the statement, so there's no purpose in using start transaction and commit in the way you're doing. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html